# Deserialize List JSON C#

Tags: c#, json

No meu programa eu faço um GET e obtenho o seguinte:

```
 {"totalcount":2,"count":2,"sort":1,"order":"ASC","data":[{"2":8283,"1":"Teste","12":6,"15":"2018-03-29 11:30:04","19":"2018-03-29 15:13:18","10":5,"4":981,"5":981,"8":null,"159":0,"7":"Others > Management","18":null,"82":0},{"2":8282,"1":"TESTE AFD","12":5,"15":"2018-03-29 11:14:24","19":"2018-04-02 08:58:50","10":3,"4":981,"5":981,"8":null,"159":0,"7":"Services > I need to bill a new client without a software license.","18":null,"82":0}],"content-range":"0-1/2"}
```

Mas nem todos estes dados me interessam, eu quero fazer uma lista que contenha os ID's dos tickets filtrados. 
Ou seja, dentro deste json existe um campo chamado data, que contém o seguinte:

```
"data":[{"2":8283,"1":"Teste","12":6,"15":"2018-03-29 11:30:04","19":"2018-03-29 15:13:18","10":5,"4":981,"5":981,"8":null,"159":0,"7":"Others > Management","18":null,"82":0},{"2":8282,"1":"TESTE AFD","12":5,"15":"2018-03-29 11:14:24","19":"2018-04-02 08:58:50","10":3,"4":981,"5":981,"8":null,"159":0,"7":"Services > I need to bill a new client without a software license.","18":null,"82":0}]
```

E dentro do data existe os campos "2" que contêm os ID's:

```
"2":8283 e "2":8282
```

Eu quero criar uma lista com aqueles dois Id's, mas não sei como filtrar os dados para ficar apenas com os Id's numa lista, alguém me pode ajudar:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uma das formas que pode ser feito é a seguinte.

Crie uma classe que servirá como modelo do seu `json`. Esse modelo é baseado no `json` que você obtém no GET que mencionou.

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;

public class JsonModel
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "totalcount")]
    public int TotalCount { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "count")]
    public int Sort { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "sort")]
    public string Order { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "data")]
    public List<Data> Data { get; set; }
}
```

Perceba que eu defino um *Attribute* chamado `PropertyName` para indicar de qual "campo" do `json` virá as informações: `totalcount`, `count`, `sort` e `data`. No seu caso, o que você quer é a propriedade `Data`, mas coloquei todos por fim de organização.

Feito isso, crie a classe `Data` que será a qual armazenará as informações que você deseja, vindas do campo "data" do seu *json* e que possuirá o `ID` que deseja:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;

public class Data
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "2")]
    public int ID { get; set; }
}
```

Perceba que também estou utilizando o *Attribute* `PropertyName` para indicar o nome do campo que possui o `ID`, no seu caso `2`.

Montada a estrutura, você poder ler o seu *json* da seguinte forma, onde `json` é o resultado obtido no seu GET:

```
var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JsonModel>(json);
```

Em `result` você terá uma lista de objetos `Data`, onde cada um por sua vez terá o `ID` que solicitou.

### Outros campos

Caso queira buscar os dados de outros campos do seu `json`, como por exemplo do campo `teste`, basta apenas modificar a classe `Data` para o seguinte:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;

public class Data
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "2")]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "teste")]
    public string Test { get; set; }
}
```

Fique atento apenas para a tipagem dos campos, se são `int`, `string`, etc.

Comment: Perfeito, obrigado!